# Am I blocked by a friend on Messenger when I can't view their profile?

Tags: facebook-messenger

Through Facebook Messenger it states I have a certain someone as a friend. However, when clicking on the icon, it doesn't give me the "view their profile" option. Also, when I search for their profile through Facebook, nothing comes up.

Am I blocked? If so, how are we still friends through Facebook Messenger?

Answer (score 2):

Probably your friend has deactivated his/her account but still using Messenger.

Anyone can deactivated his/her Facebook account and keep using Messenger.

To test the Blocking scenario, try to send a message to your friend, if it didn't popup a notification that *you are blocked to send message*, then you are not blocked.

Communicate further with your friend and asked what is the actual reason.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have been blocked. A way to confirm this is to go to the Facebook app and search the person, If nothing comes up then you have been blocked OR they have deactivated their account.